# View csv data file after import it via email attachment

Tags: ios, csv

I find this tutorial very helpful To import csv file via attachment

http://blog.spritebandits.com/2011/12/14/importing-csv-data-file-into-an-ios-app-via-email-attachment/

But still I don't know how to call specefic tableview in my app to view the content.

Comment: What's the specific issue you're facing? Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: I just want to view the contect of csv file by presenting view controller. I actually don't know how I can presented or call the view controller

Comment: My code is same code in the link. The only different is that I want to call specific table view to display the contect.